# SQL find part of string

Tags: php, sql, string, phpmyadmin, web

I met following problem:
I've got table '`students`' with columns: '`id_student`', 'name' and '`surname`'. 
Then I got a variable that contains full_name (example: '**James Bond**')
I need to make a query that selects `'id_student`' where 'name' and 'surname' matches whole name.

I tried to do this in several ways, like:

```
SELECT id_student FROM students WHERE name+' '+surname LIKE full_name
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work in a database where `+` is used for string concatenation.  The `LIKE` is fine, but `=` seems sufficient:

```
SELECT id_student
FROM students
WHERE CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) = full_name;
```

Note that unexpected characters and small differences in spelling would cause the comparisons to fail.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support string concatenation using plus, at least not by default.  Instead, we can use the `CONCAT` function.  The `LIKE` expression you want here is:

```
full_name LIKE 'James%Bond'
```

Here we want any record which starts with `James` and ends with `Bond`.

```
SELECT id_student
FROM students
WHERE full_name LIKE CONCAT(name, '%', surname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like:

```
SELECT id_student 
FROM students
WHERE CONCAT_WS(" ", name, surname) 
LIKE full_name
```

`CONCAT_WS` or `CONCAT` is the MySQL function to join strings. The former allows you to define a separator, a space in your case.

Comment: This answer needs explanation.  Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow.   Please edit with the intent to educate.